# Regex Replace Whitespaces between single quotes

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to find and replace a string into the wanted string, but can't get it to work.

For example:

```
1777: '23.5R25 Bridgestone VLT **',
```

Should be:

```
1777: '23.5R25-Bridgestone-VLT-**',
```

I'm having like 1,700 lines like this and want every whitespace between the single quotes to dashes. I'm using Notepad++ for this.

My approach:

Find: `'(.*?)\s+(.*?)'`

Replace: `'\1-\2'`

But this works for just 2 words.

Comment: i'm not an expert in regex but you could replace every space with - and then replace :- with :

Comment: I'd like to know why the downvote?
Within the string can be anything so let's say for another example:
1777: '23.5R25 Bridg: estone VLT **',
If i'm using your method @Lorenzo i'll end up with 
1777: '23.5R25-Bridg: estone-VLT-**',

Comment: i upvoted you, also because somebody downvoted you for no reason

Comment: and you said that "1,700 lines like this " so i thought that the lines were similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\s(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

You can use this and replace by `-`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vP2zF2/2

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem and also tackling the problem i've had with Lorenzo's answere :)