# Remove unnecessary data/Spaces in CSV

Tags: vb6

I need help on how to remove spaces/emtpy in data without compromising spaces on other data. Here's my sample data.

```
12345,"        ","abcde fgh",2017-06-06,09:00,AM,"       ", US
```

expected output:

```
12345,,"abcde fgh",2017-06-06,09:00,AM,, US
```

since `"    "` should be considered as null.

I tried the Trim() function but it did not work. I also tried Regex pattern but still no use.

Here's my sample function.

```
Private Sub Transform(delimiter As String)

   Dim sFullPath    As String
   Dim strBuff      As String
   Dim re           As RegExp
   Dim matches      As Object
   Dim m            As Variant

   If delimiter <> "," Then
      strBuff = Replace(strBuff, delimiter, ",")
   Else
        With re
            .Pattern = "(?!\B""[^""]*)" & delimiter & "(?![^""]*""\B)"
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Global = True
        End With

        Set matches = re.Execute(strBuff)
        For Each m In matches
            strBuff = re.Replace(strBuff, ",")
        Next

        Set re = Nothing
        Set matches = Nothing  
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You've tagged three different version of `VB`. Please only tag the one you're actually using.

Comment: use `a=split(s,",")` then something along these lines on the resultant array's elements `if len(replace(a(x)," ",vbnullstring))=0 then a(x)=""`  and then use `join` to put it back together.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, you're assuming there will never be a comma **inside** one of the quoted fields; if there is, a simple Split() approach will not work.

Comment: If you're targeting VB.NET, I'd recommend [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Idle_Mind Will it matter? "123 some avenue, some town" will pass the inspection, and be put back "123 some avenue" joined with "some town" with a "," delimiter?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, it might, since multiple spaces between other characters, but inside quotes, could be considered valid data that shouldn't be trimmed...but this hasn't been adequately addressed by the question as stated.

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion. I'm using VB6.

Comment: The above function is used to ignore "," inside quotes. I will try the split() and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Try using this for your regular expression. The two double quotes in a row are how a single double quote is included in a string literal. Some people prefer to use `Chr(34)` to include double quotes inside a string.

`\B(\s)(?!(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)`

Using that expression on your example string

`12345,"        ","abcde fgh",2017-06-06,09:00,AM,"       ", US`

yields

`12345,"","abcde fgh",2017-06-06,09:00,AM,"", US`

Example function

```
Private Function Transform(ByVal strLine As String) As String
    Dim objRegEx As RegExp

    On Error GoTo ErrTransForm

    Set objRegEx = New RegExp
    With objRegEx
        .Pattern = "\B(\s)(?!(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)"
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        Transform = .Replace(strLine, "")
    End With

ExitTransForm:
    If Not objRegEx Is Nothing Then
        Set objRegEx = Nothing
    End If
    Exit Function

ErrTransForm:
    'error handling code here
    GoTo ExitTransForm

End Function
```

And credit where credit is due. I used this answer, [Regex Replace Whitespaces between single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363744/regex-replace-whitespaces-between-single-quotes) as the basis for the expression here.

Comment: i tried this solution and I got "Run-time error '5017': Method 'Execute' of object 'IRegExp2' failed". What does this mean? when i hit debug it failed in this part of the function "Set matches = re.Execute(strBuff)"

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may have to do with how your variables are declared. Try `Dim matches As MatchCollection` and `Dim m As Match` instead. Or see the example function I added to my answer.

Comment: i was able to make it work. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an output string variable and have a conditional statement saying if the input is not empty, add it on to the output string. For example (VB console app format with the user being prompted to enter many inputs):

```
Dim input As String
Dim output As String

Do
    input = console.ReadLine()
    If Not input = " " Then
        output += input
    End If
Loop Until (end condition)

Console.WriteLine(output)
```

You can throw any inputs you don't want into the conditional to remove them from the output.

Comment: upon further thought this doesnt help with multiple spaces ("      ") unless you actually go through and add every possible number of spaces into the conditional

Comment: it should be: `If Not Trim(input) = ""`

Answer (score -3):

Your CSV file isn't correctly formatted.
Double quote shouldn't exists, then open your CSV with Notepad and replace them with a null string.

After this, you now have a real CSV file that you can import whitout problems.

Comment: Since when are fields enclosed in quotes not allowed?